# heroku django channel app runs perfectly fine for sometime and then keeps giving 503 error

Tags: django, heroku, django-channels

I am following this article - https://blog.heroku.com/in_deep_with_django_channels_the_future_of_real_time_apps_in_django

Has it something to do with the fact that I have only one worker running (free tier) `heroku ps:scale web=1:free worker=1:free` as suggested in the article ?

So now it is up again..and I guess it will go down again..

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "asgi_redis.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [os.environ.get('REDIS_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379')],
        },
        "ROUTING": "malang.routing.channel_routing",
    },
}
```

Comment: please mind posting some of the logs too, as we are not so good with guesswork :)

Comment: @KostasLivieratos I think it has to do something with my channel_layer config.

I added it above, please let me know if it is fine configuration for deployment.

Comment: still not sure if you don't post logs in order to elaborate more on what goes wrong and causes your app to crash

Comment: ok, I have caught the error in logs...Its so code error which makes the app crash...but why does the app doesn't restart on reload ? do i have to use some kind of daemon/supervisord to auto restart?

Comment: No, you don't need to do that, as Heroku manages your processes via your `Procfile`.